# PDF output from MATLAB and inclusion in LaTeX

Tags: matlab, pdf, latex

I'm printing some figures in MATLAB in PDF form, and can view them fine with the Evince PDF viewer on Fedora 16.

When I try to include them in LaTeX (TeXLive 2011), however, I get an error

```
!pdfTeX error: /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex (file ./caroti
d_amp_mod_log.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed
```

However, I can take an example PDF image generated in Mathematica and include it just fine, which tells me that the problem is with the PDF's generated by MATLAB and not with PDF's in general.

Might it have something to do with the `set(0,'defaultfigurepaperpositionmode','auto')`I put in my `startup.m` file so that pages would auto-fit the images?

**EDIT:** I just tried using `saveas(figure(1), 'filename.pdf')` instead of `print(figure(1), 'filename.pdf')` and it worked fine, but the `PaperPositionMode` property is ignored. Any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the problem. The correct way to print images is to use the `print(handle, '-dformat', 'filename')` syntax.

So, for PDF's, we need `print(figure(1), '-dpdf', 'myfigure')`. See MATLAB [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#f30-534567) on graphics file formats for more information.

Using `print(figure(1), 'filename.pdf')` still produces a valid PDF for viewing, but it can't be included in LaTeX.

Comment: _Iff_ those viewable but not includeable pdfs are valid pdfs, this would be a bug in pdftex. Can you put one of those pdfs online somewhere?

Comment: Doubt it. Sounds more like it was saved in another format but with suffix pdf. http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/printopt.html suggests it likely was ps2.

Comment: That'd explain why Evince was able to open it. I'll check it out some time in the next few days.

Comment: I met the same problem and found this page when searching for a solution. The issue that I found was that I had Octave produce a file with .pdf extension, but that has eps as the content. In Linux we can use epstopdf file.eps to convert the eps file into a nice format file.pdf file that is suitable for inclusion in latex.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using 
pdfpages

or 
pgf

to include pdf files. However, you need to use pdflatex only, as you are doing right now.